# SQLAlchemy Sessions and other queries

Tags: sqlalchemy

Looking a sqlalchemy tutorials, I quite often see querys in the form of

```
SomeClass.query.filter(...)
```

And then often with a session object

```
session.query(SomeClass).count()
```

What is the deal with the first notation, I thought I would always need a session to retrieve data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

First notation is a shortcut when using [Contextual Session API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html?highlight=query_property#contextual-session-api). When using `declarative` extension it is convenient to specify it on the `Base`, however one can apply it to any model class without need for `declarative`.

In order to enable it, one should first set it up using [`scoped_session.query_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html?highlight=query_property#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.query_property), usually like below:

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base.query = Session.query_property()
```